# Find such 5-digit number 84x5y, knowing that 198 divides it

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

My first step was prime factorization of $198$: $$198=2×3×3×11$$

Since $3$ divides it, $3$ has to divide $(8+4+x+5+y)=17+x+y$

Since $2$ divides it than $2$ also divides $y$

And since $11$ divides this number, $11$ also has to divide $(5y+4x+8)$
At this point I don't know what to do next

Comment: $9$ divides it so $9$ must divide $17+x+y$ as well.  At this point you have the equations that ace to be enough... um, what divisible rule of $11$ are you using? I'm not familar with it.  The one I know is $11$ must divide $8+x+y-5-4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write $198=2 \cdot 9 \cdot 11$. Now, by divisibility rule of $9$, we have:
$$9 \mid (x+y+17) \implies 9 \mid (x+y-1)$$
By divisibility rule of $11$, we have:
$$11 \mid (8+x+y-4-5) \implies 11 \mid (x+y-1)$$
This thus gives $99 \mid (x+y-1)$. Clearly $x+y-1 < 99$ which shows that $x+y=1$. Thus,  one of them has to be zero and the other has to be one. Since $2$ divides the number, $y$ has to be even.

This shows that the only answer is $x=1$ and $y=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $11$ divides the number it divides $8-4+x-5+y=x+y-1$  Better than the test for $3$, use the test for $9$, which says $9$ divides $17+x+y$ or $x+y-1$.  Gather it all together

$y$ is even
$11|(x+y-1)$
$9|(x+y-1)$

The last two tell us $x+y-1=0$, so from $y$ being even we have $y=0,x=1$